# "attempting to reference a deleted function" on a function argument

Tags: c++, image, dlib

I know there are other threads with this error, but it seems that the error has not 1 single solution and none of the other threads helped me in my case.

I am trying to process an image using [dlib](http://dlib.net/imaging.html). I have tried reading an image, accesing a pixel and saving an image with dlib, and it works. Code that works, for reference:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <dlib/image_transforms.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace dlib;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //reading the image
    array2d<rgb_pixel> img;
    load_image(img, "landscape.bmp");

    //accessing a pixel
    cout << (int)img[0][0].red << "," << (int)img[0][0].green << "," << (int)img[0][0].blue << endl;

    //saving an image
    string name = "landscape2.bmp";
    save_bmp(img, name);

    cout << "press enter to exit..." << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I have tried to create a function that takes an image and processes it. In order to process it I wanted to use some other functions that I defined in other modules. Here is the function from the same main.cpp file as the previous code:

```
#include "basic_preprocessing_alg.h"
#include <vector>

void    create_preprocessed_image(std::string image_name, int image_width = 1280, int image_height = 720, int elem_sim_constant = 1, int new_elem_sim_threshold = 10) {

    //reading the image and saving it to a dlib array named img
    array2d<rgb_pixel> img;
    load_image(img, "landscape.bmp");

    // sending the image to another function to be processed
    std::vector<rgb_pixel> frame = image_to_frame(img);
}
```

And now I get the error. The 'img' in 'std::vector frame = image_to_frame(img);' is underlined and it says "cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function".

The basic_preprocessing_alg.h file contains the folowing:

```
#include <vector>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <dlib/image_transforms.h>

std::vector<dlib::rgb_pixel> image_to_frame(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> frame);
```

And the basic_preprocessing_alg.cpp contains the following:

```
#include "basic_preprocessing_alg.h"
#include <vector>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <dlib/image_transforms.h>


std::vector<dlib::rgb_pixel> image_to_frame(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> frame) {
    //for now it only returns an empty vector, just for testing
    return std::vector<dlib::rgb_pixel>();
}
```

I have to mention that I am a C++ beginner, I have coded in Python mostly and just recently tried C++. It might be a rookie mistake or something, but I am utterly confused and I could not find anything useful on Google.

The entire error message I get when I try to build:

```
1>c:\users\...\main.cpp(51): error C2280: 'dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel,dlib::default_memory_manager>::array2d(const dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel,dlib::default_memory_manager> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>c:\users\...\array2d_kernel.h(163): note: see declaration of 'dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel,dlib::default_memory_manager>::array2d'
1>c:\users\...\array2d_kernel.h(163): note: 'dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel,dlib::default_memory_manager>::array2d(const dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel,dlib::default_memory_manager> &)': function was explicitly deleted
```

I don't understand what is the function that I attempt to reference which was deleted. I don't see how to fix this or what is wrong with my code.

I am using VisualStudio 2017 and Windows 10 if it matters.

Comment: Have you looked at the dlib::array2d class?

Comment: seems you are performing a copy of an array2d, which is forbidden here; it seem to be your image_to_frame that should take a reference, probably

Comment: I'm assuming OznOg is correct, in which case you can solve your issue by using (const) references everywhere in your function arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is about the deleted copy constructor of [`dlib::array2d`](http://dlib.net/dlib/array2d/array2d_kernel_abstract.h.html):

> ```
> array2d(const array2d&) = delete;        // copy constructor
> ```

An accessible copy constructor is required in order to pass parameters by value. Pass `frame` by reference to fix this error:

```
std::vector<dlib::rgb_pixel> image_to_frame(dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel> &frame);
//                                                                         ^
```

**Note:** If you plan to call only `const` functions on `frame`, pass it by `const` reference.

Comment: why did you put a semicolon at the end of your image_to_frame statement?
Also, if he needs to use a reference, how does that prevent the use of a deleted copy constructor?

Comment: @ericfrazer the semicolon is there because it's at the end of a declaration; passing by reference eliminates copying, and therefore does not require an invocation of a copy constructor.